# VBA How to hide multiple worksheets based on current date minus 2 days

Tags: vba

I want to hide worksheets that are 2 days before the current date. A sheet with date 30th Sept (date is in cell A1) I need to be hidden on 28th Sept. I have the below so far, but when I run it, it hides all of my worksheets.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim myDate As Date
    myDate = Range("A1").Value
    Dim curr_date As Date
    curr_date = Date

    If curr_date >= CDate((myDate) + 2) Then
    
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Visible = xlSheetHidden
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Visible = xlSheetHidden
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(4).Visible = xlSheetHidden
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(5).Visible = xlSheetHidden
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(6).Visible = xlSheetHidden

    Else
    
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(4).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(5).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(6).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: When should the sheets be hidden? When the workbook opens (i.e. check today's date and hide appropriate sheets) or when a user updates the date in `A1`?

Comment: Yes I would like the Macro to run each time the workbook is opened, the dates will remain the same in A1

Comment: Just so i am clear, if today's date is not within the next 2 days then all sheets should be hidden, else show the sheets. Correct?

Comment: If the date in A1 on each worksheet is not within the next 2 days, to hide that particular worksheet. So Wednesday worksheet would be hidden on Monday, Thursday's would be hidden on Tuesday etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim dateRng As Range, sht As Integer
    
    For sht = 2 To 6
        
        Set dateRng = Worksheets(sht).Range("A1")
        
        If VBA.IsDate(dateRng) Then

            If DateDiff("d", Now, CDate(dateRng)) >= -2 Then
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sht).Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Else
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sht).Visible = xlSheetVisible
            End If
    
        End If
        
    Next sht
End Sub
```

*Notes*

1. Make sure you place the code in the `ThisWorkbook` object
2. The code loops over sheets 2 to 6. If you have a variable number of sheets you can replace `6` with `Worksheets.Count()`

Comment: Thank you very much, I amended the >= -2 to <= 2 and it works perfectly. I have placed in the ThisWorkbook object as suggested and it is running when I open the workbook. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, in A1 I have set the time to 10am, to try to make the worksheet hidden at 10am on the day required. However, it is still only seeing the date. I've also tried changing the date offset variable to 2.583 days but this doesn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could try using an hourly offset `DateDiff("h", Now, CDate(dateRng)) ` >= 58 where 58 represents 2 days and 10 hours.

Comment: It only seems to work when the hours are a factor of 24, so with the example you gave me, it works the same as 2 days and ignores the additional hours.

Comment: Example: `DateDiff("h", Now, CDate("27/09/2020  10:00:00"))` returns 47.

Comment: I realised I still had the date and time in A1 as 29/09/2020 10:00:00. I've now changed this to 29/09/2020 00:00:00 and it works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help